# Why is my VPN client not available (unable to exchange data)?

Tags: openvpn, vpn

I have established a connexion between my VM and my Ubuntu client

```
$ sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.4 i586-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 26 2017
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:1194
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 WARNING: 'keydir' is present in local config but missing in remote config, local='keydir 0'
Sat Nov  4 14:38:29 2017 [canard.ch] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:1194
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Nov  4 14:38:31 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Then from either of the server or the client I see the `tun` interface:

```
tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:168 (168.0 B)
```

But in this case I cannot ping `10.8.0.5`. I cannot manage to exchange data between the client and the server.

What is my mistake ?

I also tried to add these rules to `iptables`

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
```

On the client side I get this configuration:

```
$ iptables -L OUTPUT -nv; ip route; ip route get 10.8.0.5
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7279 packets, 1483K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
10.8.0.5 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6
10.8.0.5 dev tun2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun1
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
x.x.x.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src x.x.x.x
default via x.x.x.x dev eth0
10.8.0.5 dev tun1  src 10.8.0.6
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64

$ iptables -L OUTPUT -nv -t nat
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

$ ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Check with `tcpdump -i tun1 -n` whether the packets are sent at all.

Comment: I don't see anyting :(

Comment: So it is either a routing or an OUTPUT filtering problem (or, theoretically, a DNAT problem). What is the output of `iptables -L OUTPUT -nv ; ip route ; ip route get 10.8.0.5`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I have added the output to my question

Comment: That looks good which is kind of strange. OpenVPN has an internal firewall which I am not familiar with. But you can have a look at the output of `iptables -L OUTPUT -nv -t nat` and `ip rule list`

Comment: I have added that to my question too